# How to prevent Visual Studio from adding generated files to source control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2010, tfs

Here's my specific scenario: Using VS2010, Pex and TFS2008, generated moles files are getting automatically added to source-control (TFS).

Pex adds a "project_name.moles" file to your test project and then autogenerates 3 files at build time: project_name.Designer.cs, project_name.Moles.dll, and project_name.Moles.xml. I want to keep the *.moles files in TFS (it's source code) but I don't want the 3 generated files to be in TFS (they are still part of the project, but they are generated when first built on a new system).

There are two reasons I need this behavior:
1. It's not a good idea to store generated code in source-control (let's not debate the merits of that here).
2. Specially, the DLL file is BAD because every time someone builds, all moles files are regenerated and thus all files are checked-out and DLL files are checked-out EXCLUSIVELY (non-mergable) and so other people can no longer build on their local box.

The [Pex/Moles team are working on this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/pex/thread/65cab91a-fbcd-4d05-81c6-94dd91853efa) but the solution is still likely several months away.

Is there a csproj property that can be assigned to these project files so that they are in the project but not managed by version control? I don't mind hand-editing the csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

Moles will not be adding any files to the project in the next version (v0.94). It will use MSBuild to generate the assemblies on demand.

Comment: Yup... but that's several months away probably. I guess I'll just have to wait :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends more on the version control tool than Visual Studio, as usually you can set up some kind of filters in your version control configuration in order to exclude some files/paths.

E.g. if you use Mercurial/Hg, you can (and should) edit your repository `.hgignore` file and specify e.g. to exclude all `*.moles` files and the whole sub-tree `MolesAssemblies\*`. I guess other version control systems have similar options.

Comment: Ok, I've just noticed you're using TFS source control. Hasn't it anything like that?